# How to tell if OneDrive file synce has completed

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, onedrive

I have a MS Access database which copies the database to a OneDrive folder upon shutting down.  I don't want Access to completely exit until the copy has completed copying the file to the OneDrive cloud.  I haven't been able to figure out how to check for this.  Using VBA I've tried looking to see if the file exists (it does) and if the filesizes are the same (they are), but I can see that it's still synching.

When I look at the file properties/details, I can see that it's marked as "Available offline".  I don't see any way to set this to be Available Online Only.  I'm running Windows 10.

-- Geoff

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that I've found was to map the OneDrive to a network drive as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qm1Of4eFDDY and then do the copy to the mapped drive.  The copy completes when then entire file is on the cloud.

-- Geoff